# I'm having an error `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')`, i tried every solution still now working

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I'm currently building my Login-Section in my `App.js`, what i'm trying to do is when I click the `TouchableOpacity` it will go to my `Chat.js`.

I've tried some tutorials and tried reading github post and still no result.

```
\\ App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator, withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';
import Chat from './screens/Chat';

export default class App extends Component {


  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };


  }

  render()
    {
        return(
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={style.container}>
            <View style={style.container}>
            <View style={style.logoContainer}>
                <Image 
                style={style.logo}
                source={require('./logo/doctor-logo.png')}></Image>

                <Text style={style.title} value={this.state.username}>EXAMPLE USERNAME</Text>

            </View>
            <View style={style.formContainer}>
                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Email"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                onChangeText ={(username) => this.setState({username})}
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                value={this.state.username}></TextInput>

                <TextInput style={styles.input} 
                placeholder="Password"
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                secureTextEntry
                onChangeText ={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                value={this.state.password}></TextInput>

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}
                onPress={this.btnClick}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
            </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
  btnClick = () => {
      alert(this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat'))
  }

}

const style = StyleSheet.create({

    container:
    {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#3498db'
    },
    logoContainer:
    {
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexGrow: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    logo:
    {
        width:100,
        height: 100
    },
    title:
    {
        color: "#fff",
        marginTop: 10,
        width: 140,
        textAlign: 'center',
        opacity: 0.9   }
});


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container:
    {
        padding:20,
        backgroundColor: '#3498db'
    },
    input:
    {
        height:40,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
        marginBottom: 15,
        color: '#FFF',
        paddingHorizontal: 20
    },
    buttonContainer:
    {
        backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
        paddingVertical: 15
    },
    buttonText:
    {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#ffffff',
        fontWeight: '700'
    }

});


//Chat.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import { Dialogflow_V2 } from 'react-native-dialogflow';

import { dialogflowConfig } from '../env';

const BOT_USER = {
  _id: 2,
  name: 'FAQ Bot',
  avatar: 'https://i.imgur.com/7k12EPD.png'
};

class Chat extends Component {

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
  }
  state = {
    messages: [
      {
        _id: 1,
        text: `Hi! I am the Virtual Assistant  from Jscrambler.\n\nHow may I help you with today?`,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        user: BOT_USER
      }
    ]
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Dialogflow_V2.setConfiguration(
      dialogflowConfig.client_email,
      dialogflowConfig.private_key,
      Dialogflow_V2.LANG_ENGLISH_US,
      dialogflowConfig.project_id
    );
  }

  handleGoogleResponse(result) {
    let text = result.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text[0];
    this.sendBotResponse(text);
  }

  onSend(messages = []) {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages)
    }));

    let message = messages[0].text;
    Dialogflow_V2.requestQuery(
      message,
      result => this.handleGoogleResponse(result),
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }

  sendBotResponse(text) {
    let msg = {
      _id: this.state.messages.length + 1,
      text,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      user: BOT_USER
    };

    this.setState(previousState => ({
      messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, [msg])
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
        <GiftedChat
          messages={this.state.messages}
          onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
          user={{
            _id: 1
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Chat;

//index.js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {Component} from 'react'
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Chat from './screens/Chat';

export default class reactNavigationSample extends Component{

    render(){
        const {navigation} = this.props;
        return (
            <App navigation={navigation}/>
        )
    }
}

const Tite = StackNavigator({
    App: {screen: App},
    Chat: {screen: Chat}
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Tite);
```

I expect it to navigate to the `Chat.js` Screen, but the error undefined is not an object shows up.

Comment: Remove reactNavigationSample() method from index.js

Comment: Still no luck, it doesn't work.

Comment: Why have you wrapped it in alert? `console.log(this.props)` inside `componentDidMount()` and check if navigation is actually there. If it's not, the problem is with how your component is connected with `react-navigation`.

Comment: Do you have other solutions on this matter?

Comment: @RohitKashyap just tried to see if there's a return value, what is the exact code that i should type?

Comment: The `Chat.js` is working properly, the `this.props.navigation` in the `App.js` is not.

Comment: There's a problem with your navigation configuration, have a look at that. Because the navigation props are not being passed down there, this is the only possible explanation.

Comment: Where should I check the navigation configuration?.

Comment: You must have a file where you have defined the react-navigation config i.e, probably inside createStackNavigator function.

Comment: appName is (has to be) the name of your App?

Comment: I can't see anything, btw i'm new to react native.

Comment: Try replacing onPress={this.btnClick} with onPress={() => this.btnClick() }

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani are you suggesting that i should change the class name in the `index.js` ?

Comment: No. In your code **AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Tite);** appName has to be the name of your App like 'SampleApp'. If it did't work, try replacing onPress method as I defined above

Comment: You have to setup stacknavigation first, where you define screens. Can you show us that?

Comment: @NodirNasirov I defined my screens in my index.js  `const Tite = StackNavigator({
    App: {screen: App},
    Chat: {screen: Chat}`
});

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani both didn't work already tried it.